# Filtering users by custom field in Azure AD B2C Rest Api

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

In azure B2c directory I declared Boolean custom field named IsCommercial. Previously there were created users in directory. Now I am trying to get users filtered by IsCommercial custom field. 
So if I trying to get users via Rest API where  IsCommercial=true then it's working fine. But I can't filter users where IsCommercail=false or IsCommercial=null for previously created users. When  IsCommercail=false it's returns nothing because all previously created user doesn't have a such custom field value, I understand that, but for IsCommercial=null it returns error.
So

filter = $"$filter={extendedProperty.Name} eq true";

working perfectly and return filtered data.
But when I am trying to get users without the custom attribut value:

```
filter = $"$filter={extendedProperty.Name} eq null";
```

it throw an error 'Internal server error'.
Is there a way to get users where extendedProperty value is null?

**UPD:**
I was trying Joy's solution:

```
filter = $"$filter={extendedProperty.Name} eq $false"
```

Still returns error, but now:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unsupported Query."},"requestId":"018ebd6e-561e-4796-ad52-296ab792f968","date":"2018-11-14T09:23:18"}}
```

Comment: Try to use `$false` instead of `false`.

Comment: Does my solution work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It returns 400 code with next body: {"odata.error":{"code":"Request_UnsupportedQuery","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Unsupported Query."},"requestId":"018ebd6e-561e-4796-ad52-296ab792f968","date":"2018-11-14T09:23:18"}}